# Call shell command from within Google Chrome

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, ubuntu-18.04

I've used the chrome-gnome-shell that offers a way to install ubuntu extensions from within google chrome.

I frequently use simple .sh script via terminal that operates on inputed text. So is there a way to call this .sh script from within Chrome?

EDIT: My script writes to disk so emulator wouldn't be enough.

Answer (score 0):

So closest thing i have now is ssh to my localhost via https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell-app/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo/related?hl=en and execute command from there.

If anyone have better idea then go ahead.